# Android: Getting a specific text from a TextView with a ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, textview

I have a `ListView`, with three `TextViews` in each row, that is populated from a Database. The first `TextView` contains the **_id**. When I click on an item, an `AlertDialog` pops up asking if I want to delete the item. How do I extract the information from a specific `TextView`, in order to update the Database accordingly?

Here is the code snippet I have so far:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Delete this reminder?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //I need the _id to remove the selected item.
                    db.deleteContact();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
      }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be if you got the information from the database that is driving the adapter. You already have the position of the clicked item and the data from your database. 
Another possibility is in the `onClick` method to do

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourFirstTextView); 
String id = tv.getText().toString();
```